# Java de-allocate an object from the heap

Tags: java, memory-management, heap-memory

In Java, to unload an object from the heap, is it sufficient to simply write `myObject = null;` and the GC will take care of it from there?

**EDIT :** Ok let me explain my use case, since everyone is assuming that I shouldn't explicitly null objects, I shouldn't worry about it, etc. That's missing the point. I am serializing an object, and am "consuming" a field of this object before I serialize it in order to save disk space. And before you jump down my throat for this, too, I cannot declare this field `transient` because I am including this field in the object sometimes, but not others.

Does setting an object to `null` have any effect on the GC?

Comment: The point of having GC is that you shouldn't even *know*, let alone worry about this - why do you think you need to? And in fact, you can't know - GC authors are clever folks, the least GCs will go out of their way to free objects once the last reference is lost but rather collect at some point in the future or not at all if you never run out of memory.

Comment: Yes, you can know. *sigh* See my answer below.

Comment: @dty: Well, I meant from inspecting the source alone.

Comment: @delnan: Well, you never said that and I'm not a mind reader. :-) I still disagree though. In many simple cases, it's obvious when there are no more references to an object!

Comment: @dty: The point is that no more references to an object doesn't mean that it will be garbage collected - it may be from that point, but it doesn't have to. Well, at least that's how it works in every GC'd language I know enough about to know that the GC algorithm is impementation defined.

Comment: @dty: I believe you know that, but saying "In many simple cases, it's obvious when there are no more references to an object!" in a discussion whether one can know when an object is GC'd could be understoond as this. Also, it was what I meant to say in my original comment when you showed up and showed up a minor factual error in it ;)

Comment: OK, I'm not getting into a fight. Here's how it looks from my perspective: the OP asked "can you know when an obejct is GC'd" (although it looks like that part of the question has somehow disappeared from the edit history), and you said "...in fact, you can't know...", and I said "yes, you can know". Then you wandered into the realm of static source code analysis... Meh.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In some modern VMs, actively setting a reference to null hinders the garbage collector. You should just forget about that.

For knowing when an object is garbage collected, look at the `java.lang.ref` package - although I can honestly say that in 16 years of Java programming, I've never needed to know when an object is garbage collected.

Can you elaborate on why you think you need this?

Comment: How does setting a reference to `null` hinders the garbage collector?

Comment: You know, it was in a presentation from the JRockit guys back in the BEA days, and I can never ever find it when someone challenges me... Something to do with marking the reference variable as recently used... I can't really remember. It made sense at the time though!

Comment: @dty [IBM GC article](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp01274/index.html#3.2)

Comment: I'm not about to read that article, and I don't know whether you're agreeing with me or not, but note that this question and my answer are over 6 years old, so it's very likely that Java GC technology has moved on since I wrote it.

Answer (score 1):

No; *all* references to that object must be lost/nulled. In practice this is something you shouldn't worry about.

Your object will be de-allocated when it is no longer used. Just be aware that any references left to the object will keep the object on the heap and simply assigning null to any single reference will not cause the underlying object to magically go away.

Answer (score 0):

No, and no. `myObject = null;` will only help if there are no other references to the object, and in most cases it's superfluous because local objects go out of scope at the end of each method.

As for when objects are actually deallocated, that's completely up to the GC. What you can do is add a [finalize method](http://www.codeguru.com/java/tij/tij0051.shtml) that will be called just before the object is deallocated, but this is problematic as well and should not be relied on.

Comment: That's not all you can do, at all! In fact, it's actively discouraged.

Comment: @dty: I'm not sure what you're referring to, but if it's about setting references to null, there are some rare cases where it can definitely be beneficial, namely if you have a long-running method that allocates a large object graph which is used for part of the method but then becomes unnecessary.

Comment: And of course, for non-local variables of object which have to live longer than the object referred too.